# Magento 2.4.6. Unable to save the token in the database

Tags: magento2.4.6

My situation:

I created a new token_table (with InstallSchema.php) to store the token that will be needed when sending an API request to my endpoint.

Now I managed to create a form where admin user can enter the token and save it.

But after clicking on the "Save" button I get the following:

[image]

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be?

app\code\Dev\RestApi\Block\Adminhtml\Token\Edit\Form.php

```
<?php

namespace Dev\RestApi\Block\Adminhtml\Token\Edit;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;

class Form extends Generic
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                    'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save'),
                    'method' => 'post'
                ],
            ]
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('Token Information')]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'token',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'token',
                'label' => __('Token'),
                'title' => __('Token'),
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

app\code\Dev\RestApi\Controller\Adminhtml\Token\Save.php

```
<?php


namespace Dev\RestApi\Controller\Adminhtml\Token;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Dev\RestApi\Model\TokenFactory;

class Save extends Action
{
    protected $tokenFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        TokenFactory $tokenFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->tokenFactory = $tokenFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        if ($data) {
            try {
                $tokenModel = $this->tokenFactory->create();
                $tokenModel->setData($data);
                $tokenModel->save();

                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Token has been saved.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
                return;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
    }
}
```

app\code\Dev\RestApi\view\adminhtml\layout\dev_controller_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="page.title">
        <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Module</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Dev\RestApi\Block\Adminhtml\Token\Edit" name="token_edit" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your route, it looks like you didn't create adminhtml route like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="mageplaza_helloworld" frontName="mageplaza_helloworld">
            <module name="Dev_RestApi"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

that's why its returning the 404 Url. Please follow the full instruction here: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html

Comment: Hello!
Thanks for your reply!

I just downloaded this example and I see the same problem in this module.

I tried deleting a record from the database and got exactly the same problem.

Also, based on your recommendation on routes.xml I have everything the same, the only difference is the line -> 
<route id="dev_restapi" frontName="dev_restapi">

Comment: So is it work for you? or is it still running 404 URL?

Comment: Unfortunately I still see the 404 error code

Comment: Can you send me your whole module code? So I can try and. fix this